# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header still appear when request using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

My app is running with NodeJS, ReactJS.

ReactJS:

```
axios.post("https://api.myrealdomain.com/upload_file", data).then(res => {...}
```

I had already setup with allowing all **"Access-Control-Allow"** and even used **app.use(cors())** but still have the same error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myrealdomain.com/upload_file'
> from origin 'https://myrealdomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

NodeJS:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});
...
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I don't know whether it is related to https, because these NodeJS and ReactJS are setup with https(jwilder, letsencrypt, nginx-proxy)

I can access both NodeJS and ReactJS with (https://api.myrealdomain.com, https://myrealdomain.com)

version in NodeJS:

```
node: 12
"express": "^4.17.1",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
```

version in ReactJS:

```
"axios": "^0.20.0",
```

Comment: Can you try to hit the rest endpoint from Postman, and verify once if the cors headers are present.

Comment: @vikashvik postman is working, and also Postman showed access-control-allow headers that I configured in NodeJS